# How to install and run phpize

Tags: php

I have been meaning to install `ffmpeg` as an extension to my PHP setup. So before I can install it, I need to `phpize` it. I installed `php5-dev` by `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`. But now when I run `phpize` I get the following error :

```
phpize
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

The location of my php.ini is `/usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini`

From another online resource I tried this

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool m4
```

But all of them are already installed.

Locate config.m4 didn't return anything.

Any pointers here how I can get `phpize` and thus, `ffmpeg` up and running?

Answer (score 604, accepted):

For recent versions of Debian/Ubuntu (Debian 9+ or Ubuntu 16.04+) install the `php-dev` dependency package, which will automatically install the correct version of `php{x}-dev` for your distribution:

```
sudo apt install php-dev
```

### Older versions of Debian/Ubuntu:

For PHP 5, it's in the php5-dev package.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

For PHP 7.x (from rahilwazir comment):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.x-dev
```

### RHEL/CentOS/yum

```
yum install php-devel # see comments
```

Comment: I am new to ubuntu... when i type this command it asks me are u root  ..how to get permission to root ?

Comment: prepend 'sudo' to the command, to get `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`

Comment: if using yum instead of apt-get, the appropriate package is called php-devel

Comment: yum install php-devel on rhel/centos

Comment: After installing php5-dev, Also check the directory in which you are running this command. It should contain .m4 file

Comment: You may have to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
to update your repositories

Comment: How can this be the solution? In the question he said, he already installed php5-dev.

Comment: For PHP7, you can use `php7.0-dev`

Comment: For PHP7.1, use `php7.1-dev`

Comment: For PHP 5.6 use php5.6-dev

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7*-dev` will grab the version installed with your system. Make sure to update the major version (when that changes eventually)

Comment: On my installation which uses cpanel, I had the php-devel package installed, but needed to use the full path name to execute phpize: `/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/phpize`, Reference: [cpanel forums](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/phpize-command-not-found.565021/)

Comment: For PHP[Y] use php[y]-dev

Comment: For PHP7.2, use php7.2-dev

Answer (score 85):

For PHP7 Users

7.1

> sudo apt install php7.1-dev

7.2

> sudo apt install php7.2-dev

7.3

> sudo apt install php7.3-dev

7.4

> sudo apt install php7.4-dev

If not sure about your PHP version, simply run command `php -v`

Comment: you don't really need to type apt-get anymore.  apt install is the same.  apt-cache no longer needs to be typed anymore either just apt search

Comment: php7.0-dev is not found in the package list for me.  Weird, I see php5-dev in the list, but no php7.0 packages at all.

Comment: @SolomonClosson It depends on the OS version you use.

Comment: If you install package php-dev instead, PHP will always upgrade to the latest stable release. If you install php7.0-dev and PHP 7.1 is released, you generally won't be upgraded to it.

Comment: Could you update your answer and add the solution for PHP 8? Now that PHP8 alpha 1 is here...

Answer (score 30):

Ohk.. I got it running by typing `/usr/bin/phpize` instead of only `phpize`.

Comment: In which case /usr/bin is not in your PATH, but I'm guessing it should be. Do `PATH=$PATH\:/usr/bin; export PATH`, and `phpize` will work in the future.

Comment: I got this error message


"ffmpeg shared libraries not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option"


I am using this command "phpize" it is working but whene I am running this "./configure && make" this error  comes

Answer (score 16):

Under Redhat Enterprise / CentOS, use `yum` to install the `php-devel` module:

```
yum install php-devel
```

For PHP 7, you need:

```
yum install php70-php-devel
```

Comment: This results in `No package php-devel available` for me.

Comment: For PHP7, I needed to use `php70-php-devel`

Comment: `yum install php72-php-devel` for PHP 7.2

Comment: and use this `ln -s /opt/remi/php72/root/bin/phpize  /usr/bin/phpize`

Comment: No match for argument: php74-php-devel

Comment: Or you could do this `scl enable php70 bash`

Answer (score 9):

**Step - 1:** If you are unsure about the php version installed, 
then first run the following command in terminal

```
php -v
```

**Output:** the above command will output the php version installed on your machine, mine is 7.2

```
PHP 7.2.3-1ubuntu1 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2018 22:03:58) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.3-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**Step 2:** Then to install phpize run the following command, Since my php version is 7.2.3. i will replace it with 7.2, so the command will be,

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
```

**Step 3:** Done!

**Alternate method(Optional):**
To automatically install the phpize version based on the php version installed on your machine run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev
```

This command will automatically detect the appropriate version of php installed and will install the matching phpize for the same.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm... actually i dont know how this solved it? But the following steps solved it for me:

```
find / -name 'config.m4'
```

Now look if the config.m4 is anywhere in a folder of that stuff you want to phpize. Go to that folder and run phpize directly in there.

Answer (score 6):

For ubuntu 14.04LTS with php 7, issue:

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev
```

Then install:

```
pecl install memcache
```

Comment: please wrap your code bits with backticks so that it is displayed as code

Comment: Actually, using just php-dev will install the version currently released and maintained for your distro. So on Ubuntu 12 it will install php5-dev.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 16.04, you can install `phpize` with the command

```
aptitude install php7.1-dev // for php 7.1
```

which is equivalent to

```
apt-get install php7.1-dev // for php 7.1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're having problems with phpize not found on CentOS7.x after you have installed the relevant devel tools for your version/s of PHP, this path finally worked for me:

For PHP 7.2.x

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/phpize
```

For PHP 7.3.x

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/phpize
```

For PHP 7.4.x

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/phpize
```

Run this in your folder containing the downloaded PHP extension, for example in line 3 below:

## Example based on installing the PHP v7.3.x Brotli Extension from https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli

```
git clone --recursive --depth=1 https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli.git
cd /php-ext-brotli
/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/bin/php-config
make
make test
```

Answer (score 2):

> Install from `linux` terminal

```
sudo apt-get install <php_version>-dev
```

**Example :**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev     #For `php` version 5
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev   #For `php` version 7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course in PHP7.2

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone on ubuntu. No promises.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 php5-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmagic-dev
sudo apt-get install php-http make
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

And adding `"extension=http.so"` to php.ini (Normally located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)

Then restart Apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`).

If in doubt, check your apache logs:

```
sudo su --
cd /var/log/apache2
tail -25 error.log
```

Is http.so starting or failing?

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu with Plesk installed run `apt-get install plesk-php56-dev`, for other versions just change XX in phpXX (without the dot)

Answer (score 1):

For instance, if you wanted to use the "phpize" command for PHP 5.6, you would use the full path:
Code:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/phpize
```

Comment: This worked for me:  /opt/cpanel/ea-php80/root/usr/bin/phpize

Answer (score 0):

Go to the downloaded folder and there you find config.m4. Open the terminal and run phpsize.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem on macOS in 2018.

For me, first running `brew install php` before `sudo pecl install mongodb` did the trick.

Comment: Two things on this old answer... 1) You should also include the instructions on how to install `brew` in the first place (get Command Line utilities, go to https://brew.sh and get it, beware of destroying your Apple-installed PHP, etc.); also note that Linux users _can_ use `brew`, too! 2) `pecl` will obviously only install PECL packages, the OP was interested in `ffmpeg-php`, which is _not_ available via PECL at all...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what operating system you're using, and 90% of the answers assume Ubuntu/Debian Linux because of the `apt-get install autoconf automake libtool m4` command that you posted (and over half expect you to be running CPanel), so I'm giving you a slightly more generic solution which ought to work on any Un*x clone (including Microsoft's WSL!).

You will need at least a few prerequisites:

1. A working C/C++ compiler — GCC or clang being the most popular options these days.
2. A 'developer edition' of PHP, which some package managers call 'development headers'. In the case of `aptitude`, as shown on the other answers, you ought to be fine with just `sudo apt install php-dev`. Beware of the mentioned caveats: you might end up with a slightly more unstable version of PHP which might not be updated correctly with future versions.
3. These days (that's late 2021 for me!), for those running Ubuntu, and wishing to seriously tinker with PHP, the recommendation is to use [Ondřej Surý's personal package archive for PHP](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/). Ondřej keeps his PPA always up to date, sometimes within a few hours after release; he keeps up with the latest four Ubuntu distributions and all the currently supported PHP versions that haven't reached end-of-life status yet (sorry, PHP5 is considered completely obsolete and plagued with unpatched bugs and security issues, so it's not supported — for very good reasons!); and he provides a lot of PHP extensions, too. Sadly, `ffmpeg-php` is not one of them...
4. There is a good reason for the overall lack of support of `ffmpeg-php`. Allegedly, the original repository for that was hosted at [Sourceforge](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) but has been abandoned in 2007. The [recommended package these days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52777965/1035977) is [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) which is constantly being updated, and ought to be easily installed using [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) — get it before starting your compilation!

Alternatively, instead of relying on an external non-official PHP extension (albeit one that is both popular and updated regularly!), you ought to launch the `ffmpeg` binary using `shell_exec()`. This is the [officially recommended approach](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP), mostly because converting videos always takes a long time, and the authors of that recommendation suggest a simple architecture where the PHP script basically launches `ffmpeg` in the background, accepting batches of videos for processing. The page is a bit old, but the technique shown is sound.

Answer (score 0):

I am using XAMPP on Linux mint and it is by default installed if your don't have

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
// or
sudo apt-get install php-dev
```

[know more](https://techglimpse.com/install-phpize-ubuntu-tutorial/)