# Pecl phpize failed config.m4 not found

Tags: php, pecl

I am trying to install a Pecl extension (SCA_SDO) but when I run the following command `pecl install SCA_SDO` I get the resulting error:

```
downloading SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz ...
Starting to download SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz (576,531 bytes)
....................................................................................................................done: 576,531 bytes
194 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Comment: I uprated, but then found that this was already asked (with greater detail) here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-run-and-install-phpize

Comment: The answer on that one is not useful for osx, only for linux.

Answer (score 3):

download the file, uncompress and cd to the folder, then do **pecl build**

Comment: Is this supposed to be instead of, or prior to, the `pecl install` step?

Comment: I got "Unable to open package.xml"

Answer (score 1):

Download from https://pecl.php.net/package/SCA_SDO

unzip and change into that folder und run

```
phpize
./configure
make clean && make && make install

nano php.ini
 add extension=yourextension.so
```