# phpize command not found when run in terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu

I was trying to install `PECL` extension, and required `phpize`. But when I ran `phpize` it displayed:

```
ps@ubuntu:~$ phpize
No command 'phpize' found, did you mean:
 Command 'phpize5' from package 'php5-dev' (main)
phpize: command not found
```

My current `php` version is : `PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2`
Should I install the `php5-dev` version? Will it have any conflicting issues? What are other alternative methods?

What should I do to resolve my issue?
I'm running `ubuntu 12.10`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

`phpize` is a tool used to prepare a php module for building, so you'll need the dev package. There shouldn't be any problems, assuming you're using a packaged version of PHP anyway.

*(Update - for more recent versions of Ubuntu try `sudo apt-get install php-dev`)*

Comment: Thanks! Will mark it as the correct answer when SO allows me.:)

Comment: This question is actually a very close dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-run-and-install-phpize so it might get deleted before then!

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 throws "Package 'php5-dev' has no installation candidate"

Comment: It's php-dev in newer Ubuntu releases

Comment: getting "apt-get: command not found" lol

Comment: I also couldn't find `phpize`, `pecl` or `pear` on my ubuntu 20.20, running `sudo apt install php7.4-dev` worked on mine.