# PHP5.6-dev in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: php, mongodb

My development machine is on Ubuntu 16.04, and we use php5.6.
I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04) to install php5.6.

now, I'm trying to install the mongodb PHP driver through PECL, however when I run

`pecl install mongodb`

this error comes up:

```
Starting to download mongodb-1.1.8.tgz (806,900 bytes)
.....................................................done: 806,900 bytes
360 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I found out through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565994/phpize-command-not-found-when-run-in-terminal) that I have to do

`sudo apt-get install php5-dev`

however, php5-dev is no longer available, and is apparently not included with ondrej's php5.6 PPA.

Comment: What's wrong with `apt-get install php5-mongo`?

Comment: It's gone: `Unable to locate package php5-mongo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to get php5dev installed! It is apparently in ondrej's PPA.

To install it:

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev`

Note the **.6** part.