# How to run phpize with custom root directory?

Tags: php

I am trying to build `curl.so` on a machine using a local copy of the `php5-dev` under my home directory.

However, it appears that `phpize` is only looking for the other parts of php5-dev under the root directory.

The first error message is indicative of this, so I am fairly sure that this is what is happening.

```
/usr/include/php5/main/php.h: No such file or directory
```

My copy of php5-dev is actually inside `~/bin/phpize5`

Is there a way to specify a local directory for it to look for tools?

I have already looked at the answers to this question. [how to install and run phpize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-run-and-install-phpize)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by looking at `phpize5` in a text editor. Apparently it is just a shell script, and `prefix` is just a variable. I edited that and now it works correctly.