# How to install ffmpeg for PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, server, centos

I've successfully installed ffmpeg using ssh, as root, on my dedicated server (CentOS 7).
ffmpeg works fine - but now I need to use it without root access.

When i try to use ffmpeg without root access, I get the following error :

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx264.so.148: 
        cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The final goal is to be able to use ffmpeg inside my PHP scripts which do not root access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest solution is to download an already compiled `ffmpeg` binary/executable and point your script to it. On the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page refer to the *Get the packages* section for links to recent static builds for Linux, Windows, and macOS.

You can use `shell_exec()` as shown in [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) and provide the full path to the downloaded binary.

Comment: i've downloaded the pack in public_html, how to use it ? i don't understand how works a static build in php, do i need to call the exec() command ? thanks for help

Comment: at this moment php code doesn't exist except `<?php ?>` lol
i need to know how to use this library to call `ffmpeg -i 123.mov -hls_segment_filename 'file%03d.ts' s1.m3u8`

Comment: You can use `shell_exec()` as shown in [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP) and provide the full path to the downloaded binary.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe too late, But here is a updated solution:

Install the lib in your Operating System
https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian-8-or-9

Install for PHP 7.x via composer
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg