# How to install FFMPEG in godaddy virtual server?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

For converting videos I'm using ffmpeg.It's works fine in  my local server.Now I want to know how to install in my virtual hosting server godaddy.Anyone can tell me the procedure to install?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It's linux hosting server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install ffmpeg for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884653/how-to-install-ffmpeg-for-php)