# Xdebug installation failed because "phpize" failed on macOS Big Sur with MAMP

Tags: php, xdebug, pecl

I am trying to install Xdebug on my Mac, since I am using MAMP for local development.

I tried using `pecl` to install Xdebug by running the following command in my terminal:

```
 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

But the following happens:

```
hello-world:~ lois$ sudo pecl install xdebug
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading xdebug-2.9.8.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.9.8.tgz (245,293 bytes)
...................................................done: 245,293 bytes
91 source files, building
running: phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

It looks like phpize is trying to locate some files which don't exist, and then fails.

There is no mention of those files in the xdebug installation page, so I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: have you installed phpize / php-dev etc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize

Comment: The stack trace says that phpize is actually running. But it failed

Comment: Did you do `pecl channel-update pecl.php.net` like the error message told you too

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, but the exact same error occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally found the solution to my problem.

**First solution: if you are using MAMP**

First, I am actually using MAMP for local development. If that is your case as well, you do **not** need to install Xdebug.

The reason is, Xdebug is already installed with MAMP.

There are only 2 things you need to do:

1. Modify the `php.ini` files in MAMP: https://dillieodigital.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/quick-tip-enabling-xdebug-in-mamp-for-osx/
2. Set up your IDE to use Xdebug. I am using VS Code, there are lots of tutorials on how to set up VS Code with Xdebug.

**Second solution: you are not using MAMP, so you absolutely want to install Xdebug on your Mac**

If you had the same problem I had with phpize, it is because newer versions of macOS have a different folder structure.

Xdebug expects a certain structure, which is not present anymore. In this case, take a look at this article: https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/xdebug-catalina

Comment: Can you add the relevant info here instead of linking to an external source?

Answer (score 1):

Autoconf might be missing

run `brew install autoconf` and try again

on Apple M1 Silicon make sure to use `arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug` to install xdebug